# ng-click doesn't pass param and trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/mZFpdHjRVrqcWYqIZSm0?p=preview

Does anyone know why the ng-click doesn't fire?

```
<p ng-click="getIt({{data}})"> {{data}}</p>

$scope.getIt = function(word){
  alert(word);
}
```

I don't see typo though..

Comment: try ng-click="getId(data)" without {{ and }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please dont use "{{}}"

See Plunker

```
<li ng-repeat="data in data">
  <p ng-click="getIt(data)"> {{data}}</p>
</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/UJv48vbBKBPTm6kvGw0I?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` doesn't required {{}}

Please check plunker I added.

```
 <p ng-click="getIt(data)"> {{data}}</p>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Q2YRCmCDthnubU4EVOb?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` doesn't support interpolation `({{ }})` only valid [angular expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). Use `ng-click="getIt(data)">` instead